# record not being inserted, foreign key issue

Tags: android, sqlite

record isnt being inserted in the table, it gives me the error which are unable to understand. please help.

Database class

```
package com.example.nearby_places;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //database name & version number
    private static final String db_name = "nearby_place";
    private static final int db_version = 5;

    //tables
    private static final String table_placetypes = "placetypes";
    private static final String table_places = "table_places";

    //column names
    private static final String type_id = "type_id";
    private static final String type_name = "type_name";
    private static final String place_id = "place_id";
    private static final String place_name = "place_name";
    private static final String place_address = "place_address";
    private static final String place_contact = "place_contact";


    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, db_name, null, db_version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    // create table queries
    String create_table_placetypes = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table_placetypes + "("
            + type_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," + type_name + " TEXT" + ")";



    String create_table_places = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_places (type_id INTEGER, " +
            "place_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, place_name TEXT, " +
            "place_address TEXT, place_contact TEXT, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES table_placetypes(type_id))";



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL(create_table_placetypes);

        Log.d("creating", "placetypes created");
        db.execSQL(create_table_places);
        Log.d("creating", "places created");


    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_placetypes);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_places);
        onCreate(db);

    }
    // add placetypes 
    void addplacetypes (placetypes pt) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(type_name, pt.getTypename());

        db.insert(table_placetypes, null, values);
        db.close();

    }

     // Getting single placetypes
    placetypes getPlacetypes(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(table_placetypes, new String[] {type_id,
                type_name }, type_id + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        placetypes pt = new placetypes(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1));
        // return contact
        return pt;
    }

 // Getting All placetypes
    public List<placetypes> getAllPlacetypes() {
        List<placetypes> placetypesList = new ArrayList<placetypes>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + table_placetypes;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                placetypes pt = new placetypes();
                pt.setTypeid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                pt.setTypename(cursor.getString(1));


                String name = cursor.getString(1);

                //MainActivity.ArrayofName.add(name);
                // Adding contact to list
                placetypesList.add(pt);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return placetype list
        return placetypesList;
}

    // Getting placetypes Count
    public int getPlacetypesCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + table_placetypes;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    public void addplaces(places p) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(place_name, p.getPlace_name());
        values.put(place_address, p.getPlace_address());
        values.put(place_contact, p.getPlace_contact());

        db.insert(table_places, null, values);
        db.close();

    }

    places getPlaces(int pid) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(table_places, new String[] {place_id, place_name, place_address, place_contact}, place_id + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(pid) } , null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor != null)
             cursor.moveToFirst();

        places p = new places(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(3)
                );

        return p;

    }

    public List<places> getAllPlaces() {

        List<places> placeList = new ArrayList<places>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + table_places; 

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do{
            places p = new places();
            p.setPlace_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            p.setPlace_name(cursor.getString(1));
            p.setPlace_address(cursor.getString(2));
            p.setPlace_contact(cursor.getString(3));

            String p_name = cursor.getString(1);
            String p_address = cursor.getString(2);
            String p_contact = cursor.getString(3);

            placeList.add(p);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return placeList;
    }

    public int getPlaceCount () {

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " +table_places;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(create_table_places, null);
        cursor.close();

        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

Main Activity2 Class (which i made for table_place i.e when the placetype will be clicked it will show the respective places according to its place type)

```
package com.example.nearby_places;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;
    public static ArrayList<String> ArrayofName = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Database db = new Database(this);
         if(db.getAllPlaces().isEmpty())
         {
         /**
             * CRUD Operations
             * */
            // Inserting Places
            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");

            //db.addplaces(new places("Pizza Hut",null,null));
           /* db.addplacetypes(new placetypes("MALLS"));
            db.addplacetypes(new placetypes("GAS STATIONS"));
            db.addplacetypes(new placetypes("HOTELS"));
            db.addplacetypes(new placetypes("MOTELS")); 
         */}
            // Reading all Places
            Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all places..");

            if(ArrayofName.isEmpty())
            {
                List<places> places = db.getAllPlaces();
                for (places p : places) 
                {
                    String log = "Id: "+p.getPlace_id() +" ,Name: " + p.getPlace_name() +" ,ADDRESS: " + p.getPlace_address() +"CONTACT NO. : " +p.getPlace_contact();
                     //Writing Places to log
                    Log.d("Name: ", log);
                    Log.d("ADDRESS: ", log);
                    Log.d("CONTACT NO : ", log);

                    System.out.println(log);
                    ArrayofName.add(p.getPlace_name());
                    ArrayofName.add(p.getPlace_address());
                    ArrayofName.add(p.getPlace_contact());
                }
            }   

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayofName);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
                    {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      // Intent i = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
                      // startActivity(i);
                      // Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                      // startActivity(intent);


                    }
                }
            );
    }

    }
```

LogCat file

```
10-09 07:19:57.850: I/Process(12740): Sending signal. PID: 12740 SIG: 9
10-09 07:21:04.281: D/dalvikvm(13567): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 55K, 9% free 2728K/2980K, paused 1964ms, total 1995ms
10-09 07:21:04.791: I/dalvikvm-heap(13567): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.928MB for 1127532-byte allocation
10-09 07:21:06.651: D/dalvikvm(13567): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 7% free 3827K/4084K, paused 1852ms, total 1853ms
10-09 07:21:15.641: D/Reading:(13567): Reading all placetypes..
10-09 07:21:15.841: D/Name:(13567): Id: 1 ,Name: RESTURAUNTS
10-09 07:21:15.891: I/System.out(13567): Id: 1 ,Name: RESTURAUNTS
10-09 07:21:15.901: D/Name:(13567): Id: 2 ,Name: MALLS
10-09 07:21:15.921: I/System.out(13567): Id: 2 ,Name: MALLS
10-09 07:21:15.921: D/Name:(13567): Id: 3 ,Name: GAS STATIONS
10-09 07:21:15.941: I/System.out(13567): Id: 3 ,Name: GAS STATIONS
10-09 07:21:15.941: D/Name:(13567): Id: 4 ,Name: HOTELS
10-09 07:21:15.941: I/System.out(13567): Id: 4 ,Name: HOTELS
10-09 07:21:15.941: D/Name:(13567): Id: 5 ,Name: MOTELS
10-09 07:21:15.941: I/System.out(13567): Id: 5 ,Name: MOTELS
10-09 07:21:17.761: I/Choreographer(13567): Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-09 07:21:27.621: I/Choreographer(13567): Skipped 977 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-09 07:21:28.011: D/gralloc_goldfish(13567): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-09 07:21:29.401: I/Choreographer(13567): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-09 07:21:33.351: I/Choreographer(13567): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-09 07:23:04.913: I/Choreographer(13567): Skipped 245 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-09 07:23:06.793: I/Choreographer(13567): Skipped 121 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-09 07:23:13.933: D/AndroidRuntime(13567): Shutting down VM
10-09 07:23:13.933: W/dalvikvm(13567): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0f04648)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nearby_places/com.example.nearby_places.MainActivity2}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:355)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at com.example.nearby_places.Database.getAllPlaces(Database.java:184)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at com.example.nearby_places.MainActivity2.onCreate(MainActivity2.java:29)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-09 07:23:14.173: E/AndroidRuntime(13567):    ... 11 more
10-09 07:28:14.847: I/Process(13567): Sending signal. PID: 13567 SIG: 9
```

Comment: u are adding null string to an int value

Comment: WHERE AM I DOING THAT?

Comment: According to stack trace, in line 184 of `Database.java`.

Comment: Just extract the database and see whats getting inserted into it